# How to print multiple pages of large bitmaps in Windows 8.1 app without running out of memory

Tags: c#, printing, windows-8, bitmap, windows-8.1

I'm trying to print a large PDF file with custom annotations/layout from a Windows 8.1 app.
I've gotten print to work by using the PrintDocument as in the Microsoft sample project [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Print-Sample-c544cce6) and also as in the example on [Mike Taulty's Blog here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/10/25/windows-store-apps-and-xaml-based-printing-rough-notes.aspx).

Basically I generate the UIElement for each page of the PDF that has an Image control for the rendered PDF bitmap and a Canvas on top of it for saved drawings using BuildPageAsync(pageNumber). I'm using a third party library that renders the PDFs as bitmaps.

I could make them render with a smaller resolution but that is not an acceptable solution.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the PrintManager requests the final collection of pages to send to the printer (user clicks PRINT button)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void printDocument_AddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _pageNumberList.Count; i++)
                {
                    _printDocument.AddPage(await BuildPageAsync(_pageNumberList[i]));
                }
                _printDocument.AddPagesComplete();
            }
        );
    }
```

This works fine for smaller PDFs. However, for PDFs with a lot of pages, rendering all those bitmaps to send to the PrintDocument causes the system to run out of memory which causes the resulting print job to have blank pages.

Is there a way to send batches of pages to the PrintDocument and then dispose of the used ones or render/prepare the UIElement pages on demand using C# in Windows 8.1?

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

**UPDATE:** Apparently the intro to printing video on Channel9 says that to print documents and images (real printing), I need to use DirectX and C++: http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/One-Dev-Minute/Print-from-your-app.

Is there any way I could implement that in my C# and XAML app? Here's the C++ sample that's mentioned: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct2Dapp-printing-sample-9869f99c

**UPDATE 2:** To further clarify, is it possible to do the same thing as getting print preview pages does (request one page at a time) for the actual printing

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the PrintManager requests a particular print page to be shown in the preview
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void printDocument_GetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            async () =>
            {
                var pageNumber = _pageNumberList[e.PageNumber - 1]; //get the actual page number from the list based on the requested page number
                var previewPage = await BuildPageAsync(pageNumber); //get the page here (possibly release other pages if they are not needed)
                _printDocument.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, previewPage);
            });
    }
```

**Update 3:** Here are some forum posts on MSDN that are related and unanswered:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c3bd807-eeae-4043-8bda-e8bc43b06f8c/how-to-print-a-lot-of-images-c-xaml-windows-store-app?forum=winappswithcsharp

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/40d9e483-e1b2-4427-9e9e-b5e22a2f02e8/memory-consumption-in-print-sample?forum=winappswithcsharp

**Update 4:** Since there are no answers here and on MSDN for now, it looks like limiting the number of pages to print is the best option.

Comment: Can you save the Bitmaps to disk? Then print in packs, like, page 1 to 5, page 6 to 10... The number of pages per time depends on the Bitmap size. Define a max allowed Bitmap pack size.

Comment: @dcdroid I had a related question for you about your progress on this. Could you email me via the address in my profile so I can take this discussion offline?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you have any luck with this in the end? I am trying to do something similar.  I would love if you could share you solution with us.  Thanks

Comment: @Sean unfortunately this seems to be the only way to print for Windows 8 apps in C#